# Andrioid DropBox login issue

Tags: java, android, dropbox-api

In my app I use DropBox SDK for Android. When I try to save data in SharedPreference or SQLite database in OnResunme method I recieved security alert dialog "Another app on your phone may be trying to pose as the app are currently using.". What I'm doing wrong.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        logFragView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragemnt_login, container,
                false);

        helper = new UNLDBHelper(getActivity());

        AppKeyPair appKeys = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
        AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys);
        mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);

        prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(UNLConsts.UNL_PREFS,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        // String key = prefs.getString(PREFS_KEY, null);
        // String secret = prefs.getString(PREFS_SECRET, null);

        session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys);

        mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);

        dbLoginBtn = (ImageView) logFragView.findViewById(R.id.dBoxLogBtn);
        dbLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        return logFragView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mDBApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(getActivity());
    }
    @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            if (mDBApi.getSession().authenticationSuccessful()) {
                try {
                    mDBApi.getSession().finishAuthentication();

                    AndroidAuthSession session = mDBApi.getSession();
                    if (session.authenticationSuccessful()) {
                        try {
                            session.finishAuthentication();
                            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                            AccessTokenPair tokens = session.getAccessTokenPair();
                            cv.put("drBkey", tokens.key);
                            cv.put("drBsecret", tokens.secret);

                            helper.getWritableDatabase().insert("DB_AUTH_DATA",
                                    null, cv);

                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This error message means you have multiple apps installed on your phone that are using the same Dropbox app key and secret.

Answer (score 0):

I used datas from another dropbox app.

Answer (score 0):

For this error.
Remove that application which have same CONSUMER_KEY.